# Casting shadow on MeshPhongMaterial or MeshLambertMaterial in Three.js

Tags: three.js, textures, shadow

I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

I used [JSFiddle by @WestLangley](http://jsfiddle.net/4Txgp/234/), which demonstrates how to cast a shadow from an object onto a plane.

Everything works as expected when the plane is filled with just color:

```
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xFF0000
});
```

[image]

Then I change it to use texture instead:

```
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  // color: 0xFF0000,
  map: texture
});
```

..all of a sudden, shadow is gone:

[image]

This happens with both `MeshPhongMaterial` and `MeshLambertMaterial`.

Note that neither camera position nor shadow configuration is changed. Everything stays the same, yet shadow is gone.

Should texture be "told" to receive light or is this something else?

Tested on r61, r66, r67.

Comment: hmm, i just  clicked on your fiddle link and for me, the shadows do work.....*scratchesHead*

Comment: I can duplicate the problem on OSX 10.9.4 with Chrome 35.0.1916.153. Works OK with Safari.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't even think to check in another browser! Works in Safari indeed. Fails in Chrome 37.0.2062.3 dev and in FF nightly (33.0a1). I'm on OSX 10.9.4. Interesting...

Comment: Works fine on ChromeOS 35.0.1916.155.

Comment: @mrdoob do you want me to open an issue for three.js on github?

Comment: I am having a similar problem with the current version of node-webkit (v0.10.5) which is running Chromium 35.0.1916.157. Textured geometries are not casting shadows :( edit: they seem to get lit/unlit via directional light however, but no shadows are cast

Comment: Now that it's v81, has this been resolved? i'm having the same problem in Chrome - in this fiddle and also in my own project

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 63.0.3239.84 on OSX

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but just to provide some closure, I'd like to point out that the version that was having this issue has since been fixed. The fiddle used Three.js r66, but the most recent (r107 as of this writing) no longer has this problem:

[image]