# Shadows not working in r72

Tags: three.js

http://jsfiddle.net/8e8mvx09/

I've looked at a few examples of how to implement shadows, but they all seem to use older versions of three.js. Using r72, I'm not able to make a simple example work. (Fiddle attached)

Did I miss something silly or do they work in a different way now?

Maybe something to do with perhaps?

```
spotlight.shadowCameraNear
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add your spotlight to the scene:

`scene.add( spotlight );`

2. Increase the shadow Camera far plane because your scene is huge:

`spotlight.shadowCameraFar = 600;`

3. Get shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/8e8mvx09/1/

[image]

Comment: Urgh - the first one makes me cringe - can't imagine how I accidentally removed that. Many thanks for the pointer on the shadow camera.

Comment: Actually - looking at this again later, whilst I can now see the spotlight illuminating the floor, I don't see a shadow cast by the sphere.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at this again later I can still see the shadow - maybe missing step #2?

Comment: The image confused me - I thought that was the embedded fiddle.  When I try it on my computer (iMac, OSX,  Radeon 6970m) from http://jsfiddle.net/8e8mvx09/1/ I see something different. 
[Image](http://i.imgur.com/wdMuwMB.png)

Comment: How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8e8mvx09/3/) simpler example? What about the official shadow examples at threejs.org?

Comment: Simple example works as do the threejs.org ones - that's where I went first.  Your original reply here works on my phone. Maybe a graphics driver issue related to the shadows on a textured surface?

Comment: Looks like this was spotted over a year ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744246/casting-shadow-on-meshphongmaterial-or-meshlambertmaterial-in-three-js)