# Shadows don't work on my Mac with Three.js

Tags: three.js, webkit, webgl, node-webkit

I just jumped to Mac OS X El Capitan and I'm experiencing problems with WebGL since I updated only on my iMac (my Mac mini work absolutely well).

My iMac is a 27" with:

- a Intel Core i7 3,4GHz
- 8Go 1333MHz DDR3
- AMD Radeon HD 6970M 2048Mo

For exemple, [this site](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows) don't work on my iMac but work on every others... So I think the problem come up with my iMac conf... ?

I don't see any error in console
[image: no shadows]

Don't work on Chrome, Safari and Firefox...

**EDIT: Another issue, meshes with too many vertices/faces fail to compile/render**

Again, work well on all Macs except my iMac. The mesh contains 75200 vertices and 144058 faces.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791254/shadows-not-working-in-r72

Comment: Nope, not related...